# Accessing other processes in Win8 Metro-style app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am trying to build a Windows 8 "metro-style" app that will operate as a "app killer".  For those of you who have used Win8 (Tech Preview) you'll notice that once you open a metro-style app you cannot close it (without going into Task Manager and ending the process).

My challenge is that I cannot access 'System.Diagnostics.Process' from my metro-style app, nor do I know if there is an comparable alternative within the WinRT.  I also thought of building a separate app that hosts a service for my metro app to interface with, but I'd like to do this with a single app.

Fundamentally, I am looking for a pattern for building Metro-style apps that leverage .NET 4.0 components, specifically to be able to enumerate and kill other processes running on the PC.

**CLARIFICATION: I am less concerned with this specific application than I am with access that type of .NET functionality within a Metro-style app**

Thanks

Comment: Surely can't be true that once opened an app cannot be closed.

Comment: There is no UI action besides Alt+F4 to close the Metro-style application.  I believe this is by design.  you can DL the OS at dev.windows.com and try it yourself.

Comment: OK, so you can close the app then!

Comment: true.  i'm more concerned with the Metro-style to .NET4 interaction.  This is just a sample app to frame it.  any ideas?

Comment: You can move the pointer to the top of the window until is turns into a flat hand and then drag the app to the bottom, or just swipe with touch interface. This part of the drap/swipe to snap and task swap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To your specific question, this functionality is not available.  Apps are not allowed to interact or interfere with other apps.

To answer your more general question, the APIs available to Metro style applications is limited compared to what is available to desktop applications. C# has a [subset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the .Net library available, much like Silverlight does.  The same is true for C++ where a [subset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the desktop Win32/COM APIs are available.

Comment: i like this answer the best thus far, I guess I get the separation or the lack of that functionality.  I just think moving forward, if all apps will be 'metro-style' that there will be some need to execute 'administrative tasks' beyond what is in the 'Tailored' .NET45 subset.  I guess I can defer those tasks to a backing service.

Comment: For Windows 8, all apps won't be Metro style.  There is a definite need for desktop apps still.  IMHO, that may always be the case.  I can't imagine Visual Studio or Photoshop (not elements) as a Metro style app.

Comment: Microsoft representatives (architects, managers, ..) have already stated that there are no plans to rid of desktop. That they simply see metro and desktop as two different usability scenarios. Somethings are easier with touch (mobile devices), and some things are better for desktop (precision). They have no plans to rid the desktop. It sounds like your app should be a desktop app and not a Metro one. Just because Metro is new does not mean its the right architecture and tool for the job.

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand (watching Build2011 videos) a Metro App won't be able to do that...

Interaction between processes is severally limited to specific Contracts (the charms on the right: Search, Send-to).

Think Phone, not Desktop.

You might be able to build a non-Metro Win8 app though.

Answer (score 3):

Don't waste too much time on this. I expect that in a beta a close option (perhaps even a charm) will be included. Until then use a keyboard Alt-F4 or the Task Manager

Comment: Possible, but there's a lot of info about the app life cycle (suspend/deactivate) that does not require a close. You only really need a Close when an App hangs - and then a Close button won't work either.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - unless it performs a 'Kill' like the TaskManager does.

Comment: But how do you tell it (a hanging app) to do that?

Comment: We can't be Microsoft might add this functionality.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Presumably in the same way as close works on iOS: tell the process to close itself, and it it doesn't respond, then kill it.

Answer (score -1):

C++:

`Window::Current->CoreWindow->Close();`

or

`Window::Current->Close();`

I haven't explored the difference between these two (more precisely, I don't know how `CoreWindow` differs from `Current`. I could assume though...

I'm using an Oracle VBox with Win8 on my Win7 machine to develop a C++ Metro App using VS 11. I used both of the above methods. I verified in Task Manager the app was not running on both Win8 and the Simulator.